# How to add WebService to existing project?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, delphi-xe3

How can I add WebService to existing project in Delphi XE3? I would like to add SOAP support and next generate WDSL document.

Normally from empty project I choose:

> Menu | New | Other | WebService | SOAP Server Application -> Stand-alone VCL Application

Answer (score 2):

This are two projects: one to implement the WebService and another to consume it. When you have implemented the  SOAP service (you can do with other platforms, like asmx or WCF webservices), create the current project to consume, go to File --> New --> Other --> Webservices --> WSDL importer, and put the url where webservice are published, Delphi will create the interfaces to "talk" with the webservice.

Comment: You don't understood me. I have already appication-server and I must add to it webservice support. Next generate wsdl document and use it in php example.

Comment: @A.Fornés wrote: _When you have implemented the SOAP service (you can do with other platforms, like asmx or WCF webservices)_ but I have ONLY finished project without SOAP service yet.
Always I can create `SOAP Server Application -> Stand-alone VCL Application` and copy all source code from current project but this solution is unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an option to create a new, empty project with the desired settings and merge the two projects manually with a suitable comparison tool, then throw away the second project. Maybe not a neat solution from the books, but it works well for me.